# Form on submit has no values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have multiple forms on the page, they are generated with Jinja2 and Flask, each form has it's own unique id, there is a button in each form. I want to click the button and get the values of the form where the button is actually located. However, when I try to serialize the form, it is empty. All the `console.log` lines work fine, each button does indeed retrieve the form it is located in.

**HTML**:

```
<form id='{{ "item-"+item.articleNr }}' class="itemTemplate">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/'+item.image) }}">
    </div>
    <div class="contentWrapper">
        <div class="content" id="item-content">
            <label id="articleNameBlock" name="articleName">{{ item.articleName }}</label>
            <div class="articleNrBlock" name="articleNr">{{ item.articleNr }}</div>
            <div class="eanBlock" name="ean">{{ item.ean }}</div>
            <div class="articleCodeBlock" name="articleCode">{{ item.articleCode }}</div>
            <div class="articleColorBlock" name="color">{{ item.Color }}</div>
            <div class="priceBlock" name="price">{{ item.Price }}</div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="addLabel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline btn btn-success" type="submit">Label Aanvragen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn-success').on('click',function(){
        console.log('The addButton is clicked.');
        var $form = $(this).parents('form');
        var data = $form.serialize();
        console.log('Form '+ $form.attr('id'));
        console.log(data)
    });

    //when the form is submitted
    $('form').submit(function (evt) {
       evt.preventDefault(); //prevents the default action
    });
})
```

Comment: cut these two lines:- `var $form = $(this).parents('form');var data = $form.serialize();` to `var data = $(this).parent().find('form').serialize();`

Comment: The only form element you have in your form is the submit button. So what actual data do you expect to be send here? Or are you under the impression that divs would become form elements, once you add a name attribute (which is invalid HTML btw., div does not have a name attribute)? That’s of course not the case. You would need to use form elements such as input or textarea, if you want to actually submit values.

Comment: either handle the button click, or the form submit. Handling both is a recipe for confusion. IMHO handling the form submit is neater. And as CBroe pointed out, your form has no inputs in it. It _displays_ some information, but not in controls that would be serialized for submitting a form.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, thanks to the hint given by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe), I was indeed having a wrong approach. I changed the code. Here is the solution:

HTML:

```
<div id='{{ "item-"+item.articleNr }}' class="itemTemplate">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/'+item.image) }}">
    </div>
    <div class="contentWrapper">
        <div class="content" class="itemContent">
            <label class="articleNameBlock" name="articleName">{{ item.articleName }}</label>
            <div class="articleNrBlock" name="articleNr">{{ item.articleNr }}</div>
            <div class="eanBlock" name="ean">{{ item.ean }}</div>
            <div class="articleCodeBlock" name="articleCode">{{ item.articleCode }}</div>
            <div class="articleColorBlock" name="color">{{ item.Color }}</div>
            <div class="priceBlock" name="price">{{ item.Price }}</div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline btn btn-success" type="submit">Label Aanvragen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.btn-success').on('click',function(){
    console.log('The addButton is clicked.');
    var $item = $(this).closest('.itemContent');
    var $elements = $item.children();
    var x = $item.children('.articleNameBlock')[0].innerHTML;
    var articleName = $elements[0].innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: your code doesn't match your HTML. There's no element with the "itemContent" class in your example. There is, however "item-content". This is a better approach, although since you're using jquery, you can just do `.html()` instead of `[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, I edited the spelling error in the class.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I would change the

`var $form = $(this).parents('form');`

to

`var $form = $(this).closest('form');`

as parents() traverses the DOM and selects all matching elements.

Secondly I'd change the

`$('form').submit(function (evt)`

to

`$(document).on("submit", "form", function()`

to make sure form elements are correctly selected.

I would also check my html if it is well-formed, a form tag inside a form tag doesn't work.